# Why url parameter doesn't have correct format in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have to create a javascript which contains an url in code behind page using C#. But the url parameter inside javascript doesn't have correct format after generated by C#.

Example:

**Url parameter:** http://google.com

**Javascript:** javascript:dnnModal.show('http://google.com',false,365,206,false)

**C# code:**

```
string link = "http://google.com?popUp=true";
string googleIcon = "<a href='javascript:dnnModal.show('" + link +',false,365,206,false)'><img border='0' src='~/Icons/gIcon.png'></a>";
```

After generated from code behind the page view the url incorrect format. There is the code of googleIcon after I am using "View Select Source" to view the code of aspx page:

```
<a href="javascript:dnnModal.show(" http:="" google.com?popup="true',false,365,206,false)'"><img src="~/Icons/gIcon.png" border="0"></a>
```

The hyperlink on icon just show this when I move the mouse over it:

```
javascript:dnnModal.show(
```

The url is lost and the remind string is lost too.

I need some help on my issue to show the way how to pass an url parameter into javascript using C#.

Answer (score 2):

Should be like this,

```
string googleIcon = "<a href=\"javascript:dnnModal.show('" + link + "',false,365,206,false)'\"><img border='0' src='~/Icons/gIcon.png'></a>";
```

Comment: But the link or url is lost its format after generated on aspx page.

Comment: I'm trying, wait a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You are not escaping the strings properly

```
string googleIcon = "<a href='javascript:dnnModal.show(\"" + link +"\",false,365,206,false)'><img border='0' src='~/Icons/gIcon.png'></a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with two other answers, but you should try to encapsulate these kind of tasks in a user control maybe. but if that's not possible I suggest to use `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` instead, since it will give you more flexibility.
Something like this:

```
            HtmlLink myHtmlLink = new HtmlLink();
            myHtmlLink.Href = @"javascript:dnnModal.show(\"" + link +"\",false,365,206,false)";
            HtmlImage myImage = new HtmlImage();
            myImage.Src = "~/Icons/gIcon.png";
            myImage.Border = 0;
            myHtmlLink.Controls.Add(myImage);
```

I like this approach more because Asp.net is responsible for creating DOM, which means that you will be safe and you're guaranteed to get a valid XHTML result.

Comment: You have go as far as my idea. This is very good too, but I am trying to add a javascript with a longer string, and this google icon hyperlink just a specific string inside a bigger string. But your answer is very good for me to cover my research on this issue. Thank too much.